# How to handle onclick events for dynamically added buttons in cardview (inside Recycle View)

Tags: android

I am trying to handle on click event for buttons inside cardviews which i've added dynamically inside RecycleView , i am getting same id for every clicks of buttons.

Adapter.Java

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType==0) {
      View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.room_detail_card_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView1);
    }
        else if (viewType==1){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.room_detail_card_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolderType3(itemView);}
    else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.module_type_2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderType2(itemView);}
  }
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    RoomDetails details =detailsList.get(position);
    holder.Name1.setText(details.getName());
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str= String.valueOf(v.getId());
            String ids= String.valueOf(R.id.switch_1_5);
            if (v.getId()==R.id.switch_1_5) {
                if (status[position] == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Done:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.buttonId1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.switch_2_5) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.buttonId2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.switch_3_5)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if (v.getId() == R.id.switch_4_5)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if (v.getId() == R.id.switch_5_5)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//i always get else condition after button clicks
        }}
    });

    if(position==0)
      holder.layout.addView(View.inflate(context,R.layout.module_type_3,null));
    //here i am unable to add onClick for dynamically inflated xmls
    if (position==1)
      holder.layout.addView(View.inflate(context,R.layout.module_type_1,null));

  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return detailsList.size();
  }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  private LinearLayout layout;
    private final TextView Name1;
      private ImageView buttonId1,buttonId2,buttonId3,buttonId4,buttonId5;
      public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Name1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_name);
        buttonId1= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_1_5);
        buttonId2= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_1_5);
        buttonId3= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_3_5);
        buttonId4= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_4_5);
        buttonId5= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_5_5);
        layout= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.module_layout_5);


  }

  public class ViewHolderType5 extends ViewHolder{
    public ViewHolderType5(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
  }

  public class ViewHolderType3 extends ViewHolder{
    public ViewHolderType3(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
  }

  public class ViewHolderType2 extends ViewHolder{
    public ViewHolderType2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
  }
}
```

How do i handle onclicks for these buttons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can't make o'clock for one button and set switch-case inside it!
do like below:

```
     holder.buttonId1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (status[position] == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Done:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.buttonId1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
               }
            }
    });

     holder.buttonId2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button2:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
holder.buttonId2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            }
    });
     holder.buttonId3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button3:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
     holder.buttonId4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button4:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
     holder.buttonId5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "button5:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

//////Add View
if(position==0)
    View vTemp1=View.inflate(context,R.layout.module_type_3,null);
    vTemp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "vTemp1:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
  holder.layout.addView(vTemp1);
//here i am unable to add onClick for dynamically inflated xmls
if (position==1)
   View vTemp2=View.inflate(context, R.layout.module_type_1,null);
    vTemp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "vTemp2:)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
```

holder.layout.addView(vTemp2);

Comment: it'll work for me, but how can i handle buttons whichever i,ve added dynamically?  if(position==0)
      holder.layout.addView(View.inflate(context,R.layout.module_type_3,null));
    //here i am unable to add onClick for dynamically inflated xmls

Comment: @H.Goyal I add that section that you need it. i hope, it can help you

Answer (score 1):

```
private View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RecyclerViewHolder1 vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder1) v.getTag();
        int position = vholder.getPosition();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                final Intent intent = new Intent(context, Jazba.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                final Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, RatriB4Navratri.class);
                context.startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case 2:
                final Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, RatriB4Navratri.class);
                context.startActivity(intent2);
                break;
            case 3:
                final Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, AnnualSports.class);
                context.startActivity(intent3);
                break;
        }

    }
};
```

Try it..

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.